# Devolver un valor correctamente

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

.
Hola,
espero que se encuentren bien.

Hice un componente llamado RutasPrivadas para tener control de las rutas, cuando quiero llamar a un metodo del bakcend con la ruta verificar-user no me está retornando los datos, pero si funciona de manera correcta.

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios"

function PrivateRoute({ children }) {

    function verificarUser() {
        axios.get("/auth/verificar-user")
        .then((res) => {
            return res.data.role
        })
    }

    const rol = verificarUser()
    console.log(rol)
    return rol > 1 ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: Falta contexto. Añade el código de tu endpoint. Probaste con Postman?

Comment: Si, esta misma ruta la utilizo para verificar en otras pages, si el usuario está conectado y su rol.

Comment: Y especificando la URL completa?

Comment: De igual forma, si le doy un console.log(res.data.role) imprime el rol, pero si se lo quiero asignar a la variable no funciona